# Removing key/value pairs from JSON file in a certain range with Java

Tags: java, json, range

I feel like I'm really close, but I can't quite figure out how to remove key/val pairs over a certain range in a JSON object entry using Java vs finding specific entries. In addition to possibly bad syntax, is it likely my JSON library jar isn't reading the object types right based on the error message? I configured IntelliJ to read the .jar file under the external library section, so I'm not sure if it's the jar placement or the way I wrote the code (or both)

```
public static void removeTheFields(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) object;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) removeTheFields(array.get(i));
        } else if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) object;
            JSONArray names = (JSONArray) json.keySet();
            if (names == null) return;
            for (int i = 3; i < names.size() - 8; ++i) {
                String key = names.get(i).toString();
                    json.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("edu01.json"));
            removeTheFields(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.simple.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the row json.keySet() returns a Set<String> and not a JSONArray

Comment: why not use parsing library, use Jackson, try method readValue and isArray or isObject.